# Is it worth it to write BlackBerry apps for the older OS with BBX coming out?

Tags: blackberry, mobile, operating-system, blackberry-webworks

As a mobile app developer on all platforms, I am interested to know if it is worth it to write BlackBerry apps for the older OS now that BBX is coming out. I heard the new OS will have an Android player that will supposedly run Android apps on it. It seems that any apps written for the older OS won't be compatible with the BBX OS. Also, is using WebWorks a viable option? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The road map ahead for developing for BBX announced at DevCon is:

1. HTML5, WebWorks, Adobe products (Air)
2. Native C/C++
3. Android Applications repackaged to run on the Android Player

BlackBerry OS is deprecated after OS 7. That said however, there are currently 70 million (according to RIM) BlackBerry smartphones in use, none of which will likely ever support BBX. RIM will continue to support those devices and the development environments for them. If you only want to work in one environment, and want to support the greatest number of devices, both BlackBerry OS and BBX, then WebWorks is the way to go. If you only want to support the PlayBook and BBX devices then you can use any of the approaches listed above. If you can't do what you want in WebWorks, or want to support devices prior to the introduction of WebWorks support then you will have to use the BlackBerry Java Environment.

At some point in every product line you will come to the end of useful life of a product and, as a developer, have to face moving on into the future. It is going to be worth while developing for BlackBerry OS as long as doing so helps you achieve your goals, what ever they are. So you have to look at your target market and decide if it includes those users who will be carrying BB OS devices, for probably at least the next 3 years, or not.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct, legacy BlackBerry code will be useless:
[DevCon update: BB-Java is dead, no java support for QNX](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/DevCon-update-BB-Java-is-dead-no-java-support-for-QNX/td-p/1369863).
By the way, the Android player will have several limitations too. Your best bet is C++ for BBX. Luckily, BlackBerry market share is declining and there's not a single BBX device out there yet.

Update: New BlackBerry 10 (as BBX is called now) phones have just been released. Here are the final dev options:

- [Native C++ API](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.screen/topic/manual/cscreen_window_types_devguide.html) (optional libraries [are available](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/library_support_at_a_glance.html))
- [Android API, partial support](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/roadmap/)
- [Adobe AIR API, partial support](https://developer.blackberry.com/air/downloads/roadmap/)
- [HTML5 API, partial support](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/roadmap/)